# MS Graph API - Access Token Validation Failure

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am struck with resolving an access issue with microsoft graph API. I could generate the access_token , however when using that access token i receive 401.

[image: Generating Access Token to access graph API]
Below is the error ,

[image: Error when accessing FindMeetingTimes API]
I have tried with userprincipalname & ID instead of 'me' , however the result is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try adding a `resource` parameter to the token request with a value of `https://graph.microsoft.com`?

Comment: Thanks Dan. That certainly helped ! Now am struck with Access denied exception. When I tried with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/58ba374c-a3ec-4bXXXXXXXX133bd2/findMeetingTimes`. Probably will raise it as a separate question !